# Ununderstandable results

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I've been trying to scrape imdb.com using scrapy in python, here is the code:

```
class FilmDataBasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'imdb_crawling_machine_3000'
allowed_domains = ['www.imdb.com']


def start_requests(self):
    genres = ['action' ,'adventure' , 'animation' , 'biography' , 'comedy' , 'crime' ,'documentary',
              'drama' , 'family' , 'fantasy' , 'film-noir' , 'history' , 'horror' , 'music' , 'musical',
              'mystery' , 'romance' , 'sci-fi', 'short-film' , 'sport' , 'superhere' , 'thriller' , 'war',
              'western']
    yield scrapy.Request(url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=action&title_type=feature&explore=genres&pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=facfbd0c-6f3d-4c05-9348-22eebd58852e&pf_rd_r=RM5G1P98V4E47ACFWDC3&pf_rd_s=center-6&pf_rd_t=15051&pf_rd_i=genre&ref_=ft_gnr_mvpop_1',
                         callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    films = response.xpath('//div[@class = "lister-item mode-advanced"]')
    for film in films:
        title = film.xpath("//span[@class = 'lister-item-index unbold text-primary']/text()").get()
        year = film.xpath("//span[@class = 'lister-item-year text-muted unbold']/text()").get()
        duration = film.xpath("//span[@class = 'runtime']/text()").get()
        genre = film.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class = 'genre']/text())").get()
        meta_score = film.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class = 'metascore  mixed']/text())").get()
        description = film.xpath("normalize-space(//p[@class = 'text-muted'])").get()
        dir_act = film.xpath("//p[contains(text() , 'Director')]/a/text()").get()
        print(title , year,duration,genre)
```

the code is running fine but I'm getting problems in the output.
in the `parse` method, I extracted all the films first then tried to get some data for each one, but I keep getting data that is related to the first movie:

```
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
1. (2020) 116 min Action, Thriller
.....etc
```

I really have no clue why is this happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use "." before you xpath if you are looking inside an element, you are using '//' which will cause to take the first element only

```
def parse(self, response):
    films = response.xpath('//div[@class = "lister-item mode-advanced"]')
    for film in films:
        title = film.xpath(".//span[@class = 'lister-item-index unbold text-primary']/text()").get()
        year = film.xpath(".//span[@class = 'lister-item-year text-muted unbold']/text()").get()
        duration = film.xpath(".//span[@class = 'runtime']/text()").get()
        genre = film.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class = 'genre']/text())").get()
        meta_score = film.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class = 'metascore  mixed']/text())").get()
        description = film.xpath("normalize-space(.//p[@class = 'text-muted'])").get()
        dir_act = film.xpath(".//p[contains(text() , 'Director')]/a/text()").get()
        print(title , year,duration,genre)
```